# Access custom user model's field in views

Tags: django

I have extended the default User model using OneToOneField as following:

```
# models.py
class Employee(models.Model):
    USER_TYPE = (
        ('publisher', 'Publisher',),
        ('editor', 'Editor',)
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPE, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Also, i have a simple model `Article`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm using generic class-based views (ListView) in `views.py`, and I want to reference the custom user model, specifically to check if the current logged-in user `user_type` is `publisher` then run specific queryset, else if `editor` run another queryset, and so on.

I'm bit familiar with 'request.user', or `request.user.is_staff`, but i cannot find any documentation or Stackoverflow questions related to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get reverse access to `OneToOne` field using lower cased model name. In your case it will be:

```
request.user.employee.user_type
```